# Как управлять USB через Python

Tags: python, usb

Необходимо сделать электромагнит, который должен поочередно включаться и выключаться 1 раз в секунду через USB кабель с помощью Python библиотеки Pyusb без использования микроконтроллеров. Возможно ли это сделать?
P.S. Идея в том, чтобы электромагнит срабатывал от напряжения которое приходит от USB. На рисунке изображена схема, которую я хочу повторить [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините за нескромный вопрос, а USB вы куда втыкать у магнита намереваетесь?

Comment: вы должны понимать, что если электромагнит должен срабатывать по команде, которую получит из usb, то эта команда должна чем-то обрабатываться. В чём проблема использовать микроконтроллер?

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov его программировать надо.

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov Идея в том, чтобы электромагнит срабатывал от напряжения которое приходит от USB. Комьютер с CUDA работает быстрее чем RAM, поэтому не хочу использовать Raspberry

Comment: Что за чип на плате? если магнит включается-выключается раз в секунду, то зачем там питон ведь можно сделать автоколебательный контур на микросхеме 2-НЕ ?

Comment: я писал ответ без картинки, под магниты на от 50 ньютонов.) под таких малышек можно сделать всё намного проще.

Comment: Raspberry  сбивается с переключения на скорости 10 000 переключений в секунду при этом записывая видео на флешку. скорость компьютера не важна для низких частот.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если не используем контроллер, то нужно найти чип в котором есть usb и программируемый выход. Самое дешевое это чип UART на базе CP2102 или [CH340](https://aliexpress.ru/item/4000019890018.html). **Бери на котором есть выход `DTR`.**

*Если возьмешь как на картинке ,с доп выходами, то там есть ещё 1 или 2 управляемых неподписанных пина (для второго магнита) ;)*

[image: уарт]

Дальше нужен мосфет. Для того чтоб не спалить комп в экспериментах бери [схемку](https://aliexpress.ru/item/1005004051941061.html) с опторазвязкой (кубик с 4 ногами). Полевик по мощности магнита.

[image: мосфет]

`DTR` соединяешь с `GND`, `+3.3v` соединяется с `PWM`. Если нужно инвертировать включение, то соединяется `DTR`-`PWM` и `GND`-`GND`. Второй магнит, работающий противоположно первому включается по второму варианту через ещё один транзистор.

*В зависимости схемок может понадобится резистор последовательно перед входом оптопары. Если использовать USB-COM вместо USB-UART или использовать гейт-драйвер вроде TLP350 вместо схемки... номинал R=(Uвых-Uвх)/Iвх*

Электромагнит подключается к контактам `"+"` и `load`. Блок питания магнита к `"+"` и `"-"`.

Ещё нужен диод, по мощности сопоставимый с электромагнитом. Например, 1N4007 хватит для небольших магнитов. Втыкается параллельно магниту в обратном направлении.  `"+"` на катод и `load` на анод (полоской к плюсу).

[image: диод]

Он для того чтоб при отрыве не сгорел транзистор. Надеюсь ничего не перепутал.

Дальше Python. `pip3 install pyserial`

```
import serial, time

s = serial.Serial('COM5')
s.setDTR(True)
time.sleep(1)
s.setDTR(False)
```

Comment: Отличный глубокий ответ!

Comment: @eri Спасибо за подробный ответ. Если нужно чтобы поочерёдно срабатывало два электромагнита. При этом когда первый магнит работает, второй должен быть отключен. Нужно два USB-чипа? В коде sleep нежелателен?

Comment: @bluesky sleep задает время работы магнита. про второй магнит добавлю в ответ